# Why is my mount point busy or being used? Windows to WSL file transfer

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to transfer files from my Windows system to my WSL (which is running Ubuntu). I can access the files through /mnt/c, and move them to a directory in Ubuntu. But I don't have permission to open them. This question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625938/rsync-not-copying-files-just-folder-structure/626004#626004 suggested running the line

```
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o uid=1000,gid=1000
```

However when I attempt this solution I get the error:

```
mount: /mnt/c: c: already mounted or mount point busy.
<3>init: (424) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:489: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000
No error information
```

I have very very little experience on Linux (I'm using it for a university project) so any help would be greatly appreciated, assume (rightly) that I don't know what I'm doing.

EDIT: The files are .gro .top .mdp .itp .tpr, however I have been testing the transfer with a .txt.

Comment: It appears you are trying to mount the root directory of the volume with a drive letter of C to a location but that’s used by Windows hence (more than likely) that’s the reason “it’s busy”.  If that’s not what your attempting to do you can clarify that by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

In that particular question, the drive was being manually mounted, so I just modified that person's mount to add the right options.  In your case, the problem is that `/mnt/c` is already automounted by default by WSL.

For a short-term solution, try `sudo mkdir /mnt/newc`, then `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/newc -o uid=1000,gid=1000,metadata`.  Then try opening the file.

If that works, a more permanent solution should be to create a `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /mnt/
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000"
mountFsTab = false
```

That also adds the "metadata" option, which allows WSL to map Linux permissions on Windows files and directories.

I'm still not sure this is going to resolve your permission issue with opening the files.  There may be more going on.  If so, update your question with more information on the type of file you are trying to open, the app you are using, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a go and when I navigate to the test.txt file and attempt to move it with mv /filepath/ /newfilepath/ I get the error mv: cannot create regular file: Permission Denied. I've updated the question with the filetypes, let me know what other information you might need.

Comment: I also have a USB stick I moved the files to. But I'm not sure how to set that up as a mount.

Comment: Where are you attempting to move to?  You said "to a directory in Ubuntu", but your basic user account will typically not have access to most directories other than your home directory (e.g. `/home/yourusername` or `~`).  You can try putting `sudo` before the `mv` command.  If it's something to do with the Linux permissions, that should work; if it's the Windows permissions, then it still won't.  In that case, try `stat /mnt/c/path/to/originalfile` and add the results to the question.  Let's stick to a basic text file for now.  Also, can you `view /mnt/c/path/to/originalfile.txt`?